# Django model iterate fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

how can I iterate and retrieve all fields of a django model?

I know that `foo.item._meta.get_all_field_names()` brings me all field names.
How can I access those fields (incl. their actual values) on a model instance? (Except the normal notation `foo.fieldname`).

I need this in order to build a custom output for my model including its manyTomany relations.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
getattr(foo.__class__, <field_name>)
```

This should give you the field object, rather than the value in the given model instance. If you want the value of the field in the given model insance you can call it like this:

```
getattr(foo, <field_name>)
```

Comment: As you have mentioned yourself, this only returns me the field object. I need the fields value of the given model instance. Edited question accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

This looks ugly but it will work:

```
for each in model_instance._meta.fields: 
    print each.value_from_object(model_instance)
```

That said, I have another suggestion. Given that your requirement is to

> to build a custom output for my model including its manyTomany relations.

how about [serializing](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) the instance to a suitable format (XML/JSON) and then working on that? this avoids any dependency on `_meta` or any of the internal methods (which can possibly change).

Comment: Manoj thanks for your additions. The ugly one still does not solve the problem of my ManyToMany relations :( I guess I will have to go for serialization!